# get value from json using ansible map

Tags: json, dictionary, ansible, mappy

I need to fetch UserId from this result:

```
      ok: [localhost] => {"ansible_facts": {"Usernamelis": "", "_raw_params": "\"{u'Users': [{u'UserName': u'reo', u'PasswordLastUsed': u'2016-01-08T14:00:34Z', u'CreateDate': u'2016-01-06T14:34:37Z', u'UserId': u'AIDABBBBBBBZGGASHKPKKYRI4', u'Path': u'/', u'Arn': u'arn:aws:iam::590456900000:user/reo'},{u'UserName': u'rake', u'PasswordLastUsed': u'2016-01-08T14:00:34Z', u'CreateDate': u'2016-01-06T14:34:37Z', u'UserId': u'GIDAJCAZGFFFFFFFFKYRI4', u'Path': u'/', u'Arn': u'arn:aws:iam::590456900000:user/rake'}]}}\""}
```

Here is my Ansible code:

```
register: users_result

- set_fact: Usernamelis= "{{ users_result.stdout | from_json }}"

register: users_result0

- name: simple

debug:
msg: "{{ item }}"
with_items: "{{  users_result0.ansible_facts._raw_params | map(attribute='UserId') | list }}"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have a string with serialized python dict in your `_raw_params`.
I don't know easy ways to convert it back to object in Ansible.
If you find a way to replace it with JSON, you can use `users_result0.ansible_facts._raw_params['Users'] | map(attribute='UserId') | list` for your loop.